# giving first div some property in react styled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Body>
          <HeaderDiv>Your Orders</HeaderDiv>
            {
                data && data.map ((item)=>{
                    return(
                        <CardMainDiv color>


                        </CardMainDiv>
                    )
                })
            }



        </Body>
```

We are rendering a bunch of cards using mapping .I want to some specific property to the first CardMainDiv.How do we achieve this in react ?I am using styled components .

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of index and add the prop conditionally.

```
 <Body>
      <HeaderDiv>Your Orders</HeaderDiv>
        {
            data && data.map ((item, index)=>{
                const props = index === 0? { color: true }: {};
                return(
                    <CardMainDiv {...props}>


                    </CardMainDiv>
                )
            })
        }



    </Body>
```